# Replace translations when updating avoiding duplicates

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

Everytime I update a certain entity, I need to update the translation of translatable fields at i18n table (I'm using [this CakePhp resource](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html)). The problem is that for the same `locale`, `model`, `foreign_key` and `field` quadruple, I'm having multiple translations, but I need just one (the last one to be exact). **How can I update an already existing translation instead of creating a new one?**

This is how I'm saving the translations:

```
$entity->set($field, $value);
foreach ($langs as $code) {
    $translation = $this->Translator->translate($value, "en", $code);
    $entity->translation($code)->set([$field => $translation]);
}
$table->save($entity);
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Updating existing translations should work out of the box, a quick test with the latest `3.0.x` and `3.3.x` shows that it works as expected, ie no duplicates are being created. Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (`3.x.x`, see `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`), and make sure that the problem still exists with a clean app installation, and that you provide enough code to reproduce it.